# Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.ws.install.internal.resources.InstallKernel, key ERROR_IMPROPER_httpPROXY_FORMAT

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I keep getting an error related to the proxy when I try & use the featureManager command.  I listed my repositories.properties file.  This is definitely the right proxy setting as other tools use these same settings.  I tried the command without the repositories.properties file, but got the same error.  How can I get past this error?

```
C:\wlp\bin>featureUtility installServerFeatures iserver
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
Initializing ...
Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.ws.install.internal.resources.InstallKernel, key ERROR_IMPROPER_httpPROXY_FORMAT
```

repositories.properties

```
proxyHost=http://proxy.test.com
proxyPort=80
```

Comment: What version of Open Liberty is this?   Did you try using `{wlp.install.dir}/etc/featureUtility.properties`  as mentioned in https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/command/featureUtility-modifications.html ?  (I saw you tried removing the properties file with the same result).